# Function to calculate smallest set of zip codes in which all zip codes are within x miles

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, geolocation, coordinates, zipcode

I need a function (in any language but preferably a script) that can take an array of objects (lets say zipcodes) with latitude/longitude coordinates and return the smallest subset in which all the elements of the original array are within x (lets say 20) miles of at least 1 member of the subset.

Comment: so you start with locations **S** = {xy0, xy1, xy2, ...} and you want to find a subset {a0, a1, ...} such that *dist*(a0, a(**n**)) < 20 for all **n**?  This problem is only hard if you want the **largest** subset - the smallest subset is either the empty set or any single member, if the empty set isn't allowed...

Comment: No I want the smallest subset in which every member of the original set is within 20 miles of a member of the subset. I would settle for any small subset. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, I understand now.  You want a subset {a0, a1, ...} such that for every **n** = 0, 1, ..., N in the original set, there exists an **m** which satisfies dist(xy(**n**), a(**m**)) < 20.  I'll have a go at this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a greedy algorithm to get you started.

> 1. Start with an empty result set *R* and let *S* be the set of all zipcodes.
> 2. For each zipcode *Zn* in *S*, calculate the set *Vn* of zipcodes which are within 20 miles of *Zn*.
> 3. Find the set *Vmax* with the most elements - Add the corresponding zipcode *Zmax* into the result set *R*, and remove all the elements of *Vmax* from *S*.
> 4. With the remaining elements in *S*, repeat from step 2 until *S* is empty.  Then the final set is *R*.

Comment: You lost me at #3. Can you explain Vmax and Zmax?

Comment: So you have zipcodes Z0, Z1, Z2, ... and for each zip code you find all the other zip codes within 20 miles.  So V0 is the set of zip codes within 20 miles of Z0; V1 is the set within 20 miles of Z1, and so on.  If you count how many elements there are in V0, V1, ..., then you can find the biggest set - that's Vmax, and the zipcode you used to make Vmax is Zmax.  You can think of Zmax as "the zipcode that is within 20 miles of as many other zipcodes as possible".  Does that help?

Comment: Your explanation helps me understand what you mean but I'm not sure that's the best approach. You start with big cities but it seems like it makes more sense to start with remote locations.

Comment: I think you're right, and I could post another answer but it seems like you already know what you're doing - so for now I'll just leave it to you to work out the best way to approach the problem.